# Get a twig | replace to output html rather than the text

Tags: templating, replace

I've got a craft field where I have an such as:

Learn more about this great %Job Title% job.

I'm then using Twig Replace to insert the actual entry.jobTitle into the %Job Title% space.

This works great.

But visually, I'd like to highlight the job entry. So I'm wrapping it in a span tag.

Here is an example of the output I want:

```
<h3>Fantastic opportunity for a <span class="highlight">Head Chef</span></h3>
```

So at the moment I've got it looking like this, pulling in the jobStatement (The line with %Job Title% somewhere in it):

```
<h3>{{ jobs.jobStatement|replace({'%Job Title%': "<span class='highlight'>" ~ jobs.jobTitle ~ "</span>" }) }}</h3>
```

Alas, when the template is rendered, it is rendering the entries as text. How can I insert the HTML span tags around the Job Title area?

Any help much appreciated,

Stephen

Comment: Looks like this might be a duplicate of [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10134/how-do-you-wrap-text-with-html-within-a-plain-text-field).

Comment: Many thanks Douglas, indeed it is, many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using twig's `raw` filter.

```
<h3>{{ jobs.jobStatement|replace({'%Job Title%': "<span class='highlight'>" ~ jobs.jobTitle ~ "</span>" })|raw }}</h3>
```